# Regex unexpected outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
import re
pattern =r"[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,\d{3})?(?:,\d{3})?"
string = '42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234'
a = re.findall(pattern,string)
print(a)
```

Dears, what should I do to get the expected result?

Expected output:

```
['42', '1,234', '6,368,745']
```

Actual output:

```
['42', '1,234', '6,368,745', '12', '34,567', '123', '4']
```

I was trying to solve this quiz in a book.

How would you write a regex that matches a number with commas for every three digits? It must match the following:

• '42'

• '1,234'

• '6,368,745'

but not like the following:

• '12,34,567' (which has only two digits between the commas)

• '1234' (which lacks commas)

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the rationale for your expected output?

Comment: to get only the normal number with comma as the seperator, thanks

Comment: What in your regex says you can't separate 2 distinct numbers with a comma? What in it says they have to be separated by *anything*?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
import re
pattern =r"(?<!\d,)(?<!\d)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*(?!,?\d)"
string = '42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234'
a = re.findall(pattern,string)
print(a) # => ['42', '1,234', '6,368,745']
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HAyj1D).

**Regex details**

- (?- no digit or digit +,` allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` - a non-zero digit followed with any zero, one or two digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*`  -  0 or more occurrences of a comma and then any three digits
- `(?!,?\d)` - no `,` or `,` + digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
r'(?<![,\d])[1-9]\d{,2}(?:,\d{3})*(?![,\d])'
```

with `re.findall`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VQMPTW/3/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<!      begin negative lookbehind
  [,\d]   match ',' or a digit
)         end negative lookbehind
[1-9]     match a digit other than '0'
\d{0,2}   match 0-2 digits
(?:       begin non-capture group
  ,\d{3}  match ',' then 3 digits
)         end non-capture group
*         execute non-capture group 0+ times
(?![,\d]) previous match is not followed by ',' or a digit
          (negative lookahead)
```